# proving the integral can take all values in the interval

Tags: calculus

$f(f(x))=1$ and $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$

and find all possible values of the integral of such function from $0$ to $1$.

I got that the minimum value of the integral is 3/4  and maximum is 1, and one can visually see that the integral can take all values between 3/4 and 1 but how I don't know how to prove it rigorously

here is the solution question 15

https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2011/feb/algcalc/solutions.pdf

Comment: First the max is easy since the constant function $f(x)=1$ is the largest function satisfying the conditions

Comment: Intermediate value theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$f(x) = \cases{\frac{1}{2} & if $x < \frac{1}{2}$ \\ 1 & if $x \ge \frac{1}{2}$}$$
is a discontinuous function with integral $3/4$. You can smooth out the jump with an arbitrarily steep line for $x \in [\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon,\frac{1}{2})$, so you can achieve integrals arbitrarily close to $3/4$ with continuous functions. Then keep moving the endpoints of the line to generate every other integral.

More explicitly one could instead use the properties of $x^\alpha$, and look at
$$f_{\alpha}(x) = \cases{\frac{1 + (2x)^\alpha}{2} & if $x < \frac{1}{2}$ \\ 1 & if $x \ge \frac{1}{2}$}$$
which has integral $\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4(1+\alpha)}$.